# Reading firestore parents from firebase's function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code:

```
exports.onCreateLog = functions
.firestore
.document('/accounts/{userId}/account/{accountId}/logs/{logId}')
.onCreate((event) => {

    let documentRef = functions
        .firestore
        .doc(`/accounts/${event.params.userId}/account/${event.params.accountId}`);
    return documentRef
        .get()
        .then(documentSnapshot => {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                console.log(`Document retrieved successfully.   ${JSON.stringify(documentSnapshot.data())}`);
            }
        });

});
```

What I would like to do is read the value from the parent, but I tried with this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined

I tried to get the parent, and get the value with no luck. Is there any advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your `functions` object reference to query your database.  You can only use it to build your Cloud Function trigger.

If you want to query your database within a Cloud Function, you need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.firestore().doc(...).get()
```